# Are there special rules for naming and calling Procs?

Tags: ruby

I completed a Ruby challenge on Hacker Rank, but I don't understand why a Proc is able to be called with an abbreviated version of its saved name.

The proc was defined as:

```
proc_sum_array = proc {|arr| arr.reduce(:+)}
```

But it was called like this:

```
proc_sum.call(my_array)
```

...without the "_array" part of the name proc_sum*_array*

This confused me, so I changed 'proc_sum.call(my_array)' to 'proc_sum_array.call(my_array)' but then I got the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `proc_sum_array' for main:Object (NameError) 
Did you mean?  proc_sum
```

So it appears that it is important that the proc is called as proc_sum and not proc_sum_array, as it was named.

```
def square_of_sum (my_array, proc_square, proc_sum)
    sum = proc_sum.call(my_array) # QUESTION: Why is this proc_sum, and not proc_sum_array ?
    proc_square.call(sum)
end

proc_square_number = proc {|x| x ** 2}
proc_sum_array     = proc {|arr| arr.reduce(:+)} # This is where the proc is defined.
my_array = gets.split().map(&:to_i)

puts square_of_sum(my_array, proc_square_number, proc_sum_array)
```

I would expect that proc_sum_arry would be called as proc_sum_array.call. Why is this not the case?

Comment: It's probably specific to your case, you have `proc_sum` method probably somewhere. It's not a general rule.

Comment: Try to trace down the source of this `proc_sum` method, then you'll know where its return value comes from and how (if at all) it's linked with `proc_sum_array` local variable.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your help Marek. Here is the [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ruby-procs/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) to the challenge. Are you saying that Hackerrank has `proc_sum` hidden somewhere in the challenge where it is invisible?

Comment: sorry, my comment was wrong, I didn't notice that this `proc_sum` is simply name of argument you you pass into `square_of_sum` method.

Comment: It is interesting that the OP has made it this far in the course without ever encountering the concept of a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a *parameter*. A parameter is kind of like a "hole" that you leave in the definition of a subroutine. When you invoke that subroutine, you "fill" that "hole" with an *argument*. (This is called "passing an argument".)

Here:

```
def square_of_sum (my_array, proc_square, proc_sum)
#                                         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

You define a method named `square_of_sum` with a couple of parameters. The third one of those parameters is called `proc_sum`.

Here:

```
puts square_of_sum(my_array, proc_square_number, proc_sum_array)
#                                                ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

You pass the object that is referenced by the local variable `proc_sum_array` as an argument to the invocation of the `square_of_sum` method.

What this means is that inside the body of the method, the object that you passed as an argument will be bound to the parameter (this is called *binding an argument to a parameter*), i.e. when you dereference the parameter `proc_sum` inside the body of `square_of_sum`, it will evaluate to whatever object was passed as an argument.

Note that `proc_sum_array` is a *local variable* (you know that it is a local variable because 1) it starts with a lowercase letter and 2) it is not a method). Local variables are called "local" variables because they are local to the scope they are defined in. In this particular case, `proc_sum_array` is local to the script scope, which means that it doesn't even exist inside the method scope of `square_of_sum`, so you simply *can't* refer to it at all!

Note also that this is exactly the same as for every other parameter of `square_of_sum`: you refer to the object that is passed as an argument for the `proc_square` parameter as `proc_square` and not as `proc_square_number`.

Comment: Thank you Jörg, I really appreciate the in-depth response- thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now as you linked actual example, I can answer you. 
The reason why it's referred to as `proc_sum`, not `proc_sum_array` is because it's how the argument passed into `square_of_sum` method is named. It's not magical at all. It's similar to:

```
a = 2
def sqr(b)
  b * b
end
sqr(a)
```

You see, you define `a` local variable, but you pass it as `b` argument in the `sqr` method, so inside of this method you refer to it as `b`.

Comment: I see! Thanks Marek. So because `square_of_sum` was defined with the arguments `(my_array, proc_square, proc_sum)` when you pass it 'proc_sum_array', inside `square_of_sum` it is referred to as `proc_sum`. Thanks for your help!